# Not able to create a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

```
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\app develop\myapp' (OS Error: The
system cannot find the file specified.
, errno = 2)
Failed to flutter create at C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\app develop\myapp.
```

I inserted command in the terminal of VS Code:

```
flutter create myapp
```

Comment: why u creating flutter projects inside OneDrive mate. Just create a folder in your C:\. something like C:\Projects and create things there. Creating stuff inside OeDrive folder could be triggering OneDrive sync and other things.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have added the flutter path in the environment variables, if you have already added the path in the environment variables then consider the following:

1. Open VS Code and install the Flutter extension.
2. Press `Ctrl + shift + p` to open the preference dialog.
3. Search `Flutter: New Project` and press enter.
4. Name the project as per your choice and select the folder you want to create in.